# Issue in json request

Tags: json, xml

I am sending below json request but getting error while hitting in application. below is the request format. I want to send json request which will return a xml response.

```
 {
  "Request": { 


    "Header": { 
        "Version": "1.0", 
        "Command": "ActiveTest",



        "cc": { 
            "cctype": "1", 
            "id": "Test_id", 
            "Password": "********" 
        }, 



        "KeyOwner": "1", 
        "Timestamp": "20151211121212" 
    }, 


    "Body": { 
        "user": { 
            "Init": { 
                "idtype":"1", 
                "id": "88384648929", 
                "pass":"1234244" 
            },
        "ActiveTest": { 
        } 
    } 
}
 }
}
```

Error:

```
Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in prolog; expected '<'
 at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]|Param={void}
```

Answer (score 0):

Where do you send your request to?

For me the response looks like the server expects xml and the xml-parser is complaining, that the opening < character is missing.